# APPCRASH of Kernel.exe. running Murphy ODE collection

Tags: differential-equations, crash

Since I am getting many KERNEL crashes running Murphy ODE collection, I thought to use this post and collect each crash here instead of making separate post for each one, as there might be too many crashes coming :(. All these ODE's are from Murphy ODE book as is. Some of the crashes seem related as some of the ODE's are similar to each others. If someone can figure the cause(s) of some of these crashes, that will be useful. It takes about 3-6 minutes to see the crash, depending on how much RAM and the CPU used. I have 16 GB RAM, fast CPU.

If I get new crash, will updated this post instead of making new one. I am sending crash report to WRI also.

All on Version 11.0.1, 64 bit. windows 7 home edition. 16 GB RAM. Each one causes kernel crash similar to this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### List of ODE's each causing kernel crash

**ODE #50**

```
ClearAll[y, x]
DSolve[ y'[x] == Cos[2 x] + (Sin[2 x] + y[x]) y[x], y[x], x]
```

**ODE #1040**

```
ClearAll[y, x];
timeOut = 60*10;
TimeConstrained[DSolve[(y'[x])^3 - 2 y[x] y'[x] + y[x]^2 == 0, y[x], x], timeOut]
```

**ODE #1046**

```
ClearAll[y, x];
timeOut = 60*10;
TimeConstrained[DSolve[(y'[x])^3 + (y'[x])^2 - y[x] == 0, y[x], x], timeOut]
```

**ODE # 1053**

```
ClearAll[y, x]
DSolve[(y'[x])^3 - y[x] (y'[x])^2 + y[x]^2 == 0, y[x], x]
```

**ODE # 1060**

```
ClearAll[y, x]
DSolve[2 (y'[x])^3 + (y'[x])^2 - y[x]==0,y[x],x]
```

Comment: Aborts without crashing on my machine (iMac running Mac OS 10.12.2 with the same version of MMA).  However, it does consume a ridiculous amount of memory before it gives up.

Comment: Maybe you can add a MATLAB to http://12000.org/my_notes/Murphy_ODE/KERNEL.htm. The result be very interesting.